# Why Ed25519 encodes y-coordinates rather than x-coordinates

Tags: ed25519

As stated in [RFC8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1.2) and [FIPS 186-5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#page=35&zoom=auto,-210,193), Ed25519 signatures uses the following encoding method:

> A curve point (x,y), with coordinates in the range 0 <= x,y < p, is
> coded as follows.  First, encode the y-coordinate as a little-endian
> string of 32 octets.  The most significant bit of the final octet is
> always zero.  To form the encoding of the point, copy the least
> significant bit of the x-coordinate to the most significant bit of the
> final octet.

Is there any benefit to encode the y-coordinate rather than the x-coordinate here?

My question comes from the fact that the [SEC standard](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=16&zoom=auto,-210,494) encodes x-coordinates, so it would have been less confusing to follow the same approach in my opinion.

Comment: The equation of Edwards curves has $x$ and $y$ interchangeable, thus it seems to me that the other choice would have worked just as well. I don't know a rationale for the choice made.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a concern for patent reasons.  As fgrieu mentions, you can recover one coordinate from the other on Edwards curves, so it doesn't matter which you encode.  However, [as this answer mentions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25110/is-there-any-patent-free-ec-point-compression-available-if-not-should-i-gpl-lg), there were two patents, which may very well have been invalid due to prior art, which patented encoding the entire x-coordinate and one bit of the y-coordinate.

However, nobody thought to patent doing it the other way around, and so EdDSA encoded the y-coordinate.  This is easier than trying to invalidate various patents around the world and avoids people derailing adoption of standards by claiming IP.

Comment: Bernstein is (rightly) careful of avoiding patents (he [lists these and counterarguments](https://cr.yp.to/patents.html)). However swapping $x$ and $y$ to work around a patent on point compression would IMHO not have been a clear-cut defense against a patent **_if_** it had been valid, due to the [doctrine of equivalents](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/doctrine_of_equivalents). I'm sure Bernstein understands that. But a feeble argument is better than nothing in a patent fight, and (as this answer shows) some would _think_ this is a working legal workaround, which can only help adoption.