# Is there any reason to use RSA or DSA when we have ECC?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, dsa

I am having trouble coming up with a use case for RSA or DSA.  It appears that ECC is better in every way.

Is this true?

I am looking for cases where RSA/DSA is *superior* to ECC, not where it is used for historical reasons.

Comment: Tempted to close as dupe of [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/why-is-elliptic-curve-cryptography-not-widely-used-compared-to-rsa). Is there anything that is not answered in the answers there? If so, you should [edit] to clarify.

Comment: By themselves, elliptic curves are useless. It is when certain algorithms are done over elliptic curves that they become useful. ECC is not a replacement for DSA, but ECDSA is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three use cases where RSA beats common ECC algorithms, such as ECDSA:

1. Signature with verification frequent or/and by low-power devices or/and where the verification code needs to be small. The verification cost of $n$-bit RSA with usual public exponents is $O(n^2)$, but the verification cost of ECC-based signatures is $O(n^3)$ (using usual algorithms). Together with simpler math, that's why RSA can be way over 10 times faster for signature verification at usual security levels, even though it must use a larger $n$ for equivalent security level. RSA verification also requires significantly less code than ECC computations, which makes it attractive, for example, in ROM code where space is expensive and a bug can't be patched.
2. Similarly, encryption by low-power devices or/and with decryption comparatively rare.
3. Need to minimize the size overhead of adding a signature; using signature with message recovery, that can be 34 bytes for RSA (using SHA-256 hash, ISO 9796-2 mode 3 or the deprecated mode 1, for messages at least 222 bytes before signature at the 2048-bit security level), versus 64 bytes for ECDSA for comparable security.

RSA is thus a good choice (and indeed still the dominant one, I believe) for signing public-key certificates; beside inertia, in the internet domain that's mostly for reason 1 (certificates are verified often), but in the Smart Card and payment industry reason 3 adds up.

Additional arguments for RSA (vs ECC) are

- RSA was first there / is the most time-proven, and became an industry standard.
- Simplicity. RSA signature verification is much easier to code, and get right, than ECDSA signature verification.
- RSA has long been clearly patent-free. But that now applies to ECDSA as well, and [arguably](https://cr.yp.to/patents.html) applied all along and indisputably since August 2014, at least for curves in a prime field; e.g. ECDSA on secp256r1 and EdDSA on Curve25519 are patent unencumbered.
- Perhaps (but see [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/93113) [comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/210187)) slightly more quantum resilience; that is, at comparable level of resistance versus non-quantum attacks, RSA arguably would fall after ECC if it ever emerged quantum computers usable for cryptanalysis; see this other [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33186/555) and [section 5.4 of its source](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1018.pdf#page=14); note that Koblitz and Menezes are not making any strong statement, rather, their intro is (emphasis mine):

> We next examine some *conjectures* about the NSA’s motives in its PQC announcement (..)
> The NSA *believes* that RSA-3072 is much more quantum-resistant than ECC-256 and even ECC-384. (..)

Note: this answer does not touch use cases where ECC is preferable, or its virtues.

Comment: Case 2 could occur in a sensor grid scenario where the encryption is on embedded systems but decryption is on a much more powerful server.

Comment: OTOH, using RSA *signature and key generation* on smart card devices really can bog things down, and using the more accpted / proliferate RSA PKCS#1 extends the signature size to less acceptable levels.

Comment: I think citing improved "quantum resilience" is a bit irresponsible, since both algorithms should be considered utterly broken in the presence of scalable quantum computing. While there may be a gap, the authors themselves suggest "It is not likely that the gap between quantum cryptanalysis of a 384-bit key and a 3072-bit key will be great enough to serve as a basis for a cryptographic strategy." This should be interpreted as quantum resilience NOT being a reason to use RSA over ECC algorithms.

Comment: @bkjvbx I interpret this as “yes, both will fall to a quantum computer, but ECDSA will fall *first*, which might give a bit more warning to switch.”  Of course, one should be switching to post-quantum schemes ASAP, but in some cases (such as code signing), all that matters is that I have switched to a post-quantum scheme *before* the original scheme is broken.  As long as RSA holds out long enough for a successor to be deployed, software signatures based on it are safe.

Comment: Note that an EC Schnorr signature only requires 48 bytes, since it is unnecessary for the hash to produce a challenge greater than 128 bits. Signing keypair is (x, xG). Signature is (c,r), VER is c =?= hash_to_128_bits(rG + cX || m), SIG is choose random k, r = c - kx. c = hash_to_128_bits(kG || m).

Answer (score 2):

If practical quantum computers become a reality, the larger bitlengths of RSA keys would make them more quantum-resistant than their ECC counterparts.  See section 5.4 of this [Koblitz & Menezes paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1018.pdf)

Comment: What about Ed448?